# How to create a npm library with JS config file and web target?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, rollup

I've created an UI JS library, `package.json` is fine, I bundle it with `webpack` and it works great in `npm` (stays nicely in `node_modules/library` dir).

However, I'd like to make some stuff configurable via config file. Let's say, my library has a `Box` React component (it renders 100x100 square with background color):

```
// Box.js
export default function(props) {
   return <div style={{
       backgroundColor: props.color,
       width: "100px",
       height: "100px"
   }}>
       {props.children}
   </div>;
}
```

I'd like to provide a possibility to add a configuration file so that the background color is users choice color by default.

So user of my library creates a config file (let's call it `library.config.js`) in a root directory of his project and this file has sth like this:

```
// library.config.js
const BoxBackgroundColor = 'green';
export { BoxBackgroundColor }
```

And if this file exist, the lib knows this and user can simply use `Box` like this:

`<Box />`

and `color` prop will be green.

How to achieve sth like this?

The problem is that when I bundle my library I don't know if `library.config.js` file exists or not. This information is available for user of my library in user's project. It seems I want to resolve all `import` and `require` statements in my library *except for* the `library.config.js`. This exception `require` should be resolved in user's project bundling phase (when `library.config.js` file is available).

Comment: I also have this question....Did you manage to find an answer ?

Comment: Hey @HectorRicardo, no I haven't and I still think it'd be nice to have. In my use cases I just pass the config values via React Context.

Comment: Also in need of this, did anyone manage to resolve it?